# How can I set focus to CKEditor 5 with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I've created a CKEditor field and initialized it like this:

```js
            ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#note}'))
                .then(editor => {
                    noteEditor = editor;
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    console.error( error );
                });
```

All I want to do is either:

1. Set focus to the editor using JS/Jquery.
2. Or get the actual input control's element ID to just make it focus (likely a bad idea).

If I cannot set focus to it anytime (not just at start-up) can someone suggest a nice looking editor?

Comment: FYI: This is a GREAT question. May I suggest removing "jQuery" from the title? The question, and the accepted answer, do not use jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set focus at the beginning of the text editor is as follows:

```
 ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#note}'))
                .then(editor => {
```

> ```
>                 editor.editing.view.focus();
> ```

```
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    console.error( error );
                });
```